# Convert YAML into an array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml

So I have this `permissionrank.yaml` file:

```
player:
  id: 1
  label: Player
  badge: NIL

bronze helper:
  id: 2
  label: Bronze Helper
  badge: STF_HELP_BRZ

silver helper:
  id: 3
  label: Silver Helper
  badge: STF_HELP_SLV
```

Is there any way to load this into an **array** of hashes so it would fit the same format of Rails' `seeds.rb` file? It should output:

```
[
  {id: 1, label: "Player",                badge: "NIL"        },
  {id: 2, label: "Bronze Helper",         badge: "STF_HLP_BRZ"},
  {id: 3, label: "Silver Helper",         badge: "STF_HLP_SLV"},
]
```

That's the format Rails' seeds file asks for.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, it loads from YAML like:

```
{"player"=>{"id"=>1, "label"=>"Player", "badge"=>"NIL"},
 "bronze helper"=>{"id"=>2, "label"=>"Bronze Helper", "badge"=>"STF_HELP_BRZ"},
 "silver helper"=>{"id"=>3, "label"=>"Silver Helper", "badge"=>"STF_HELP_SLV"}}
```

So all you really seem to need to get rid of is the hash keys. If you only want to keep the values of a hash, you can use the `Hash#values` method to get (almost) the array you want:

```
pp YAML.load_file("permissionrank.yml").values

[{"id"=>1, "label"=>"Player", "badge"=>"NIL"},
 {"id"=>2, "label"=>"Bronze Helper", "badge"=>"STF_HELP_BRZ"},
 {"id"=>3, "label"=>"Silver Helper", "badge"=>"STF_HELP_SLV"}]
```

The only remaining difference with your example is then that the keys inside those hashes are strings, not symbols. This probably doesn't matter, since Rails is generally really relaxed about that, but just for the sake of example, let's convert those as well. For this you can use the [`Hash#symbolize_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-symbolize_keys) method from ActiveSupport.

```
pp YAML.load_file("permissionrank.yml").values.map(&:symbolize_keys)

[{id: 1, label: "Player", badge: "NIL"},
 {id: 2, label: "Bronze Helper", badge: "STF_HELP_BRZ"},
 {id: 3, label: "Silver Helper", badge: "STF_HELP_SLV"}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this when I get back to my computer.

Comment: Thanks, that works as you said. I have added a code example that I tested to your post for completeness, could you accept it pease so I can accept your answer? :)

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't yet reached the moderation status, but I'm sure a moderator will come by shortly.

Comment: Or maybe not. @Guilmon I've added some example code myself, is this ok?

Comment: I tride your example at first and it didnt work as I expected. However `YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/path/to/file.yml").values.each { |hash| hash.symbolize_keys! }` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Below will give you an array of hashes:

```
-
  :id: 1
  :label: Player
  :badge: NIL
-
  :id: 2
  :label: Bronze Helper
  :badge: STF_HELP_BRZ
-
  :id: 3
  :label: Silver Helper
  :badge: STF_HELP_SLV
```